# Email Configuration in Cent OS

Tags: centos, email

I have hosted my web application in VPS Cent OS. Its working well, in that application if a vendor registered or any events occurs between users and website, admin needs to send emails regarding the event, password, order details, etc. I need to configure the settings to do that. I am a database administrator, this is new to me. 
FYI:

1. Email hosted in another third party server (Business mail).
2. I am accessing the server using putty.

I have doubt that, if I redirected the domain name from email server (business mail), if it will work, whether the Cent OS **Sendmail** or **Postfix** will work similar to using my business mail?

I just need to send mails from the application using my business id (sales@example.com). For remaining emails (contact/info/support) I need to access the same server as I am using now.

Answer (score 0):

That should match all your expections .
http://www.mavinerc.com/home/2012/05/11/1186/